# Padding toolbar's logo in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

I have a small logo in toolbar, and I want to padding toolbar logo to right, but when I use    `app:contentInsetRight="0dp" app:contentInsetStart="0dp"` nothing change in toolbar, any idea?

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**MainActivity:**

```
              <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/color"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/color_two"
                >

              <ImageView
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"
                  android:paddingEnd="60dp"

                  />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default content inset is probably already zero. Making the padding zero isn't going to move which side the item is biased to. The padding on the opposite side is still going to be zero as well. Controlling which side the child is pulled toward is done with gravity. Add `android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"` to the ImageView.

By the way, it's sort of contradictory to set only `Right` and `Start` variants of a view property. When the device is set to a right-to-left language like Arabic, they will be the same, but otherwise they will be opposites.

Comment: I get it , tnx so much :)

Comment: More properly, you should probably use `android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"` so it's reversed for right-to-left languages, if you think you might ever support that.

Comment: if u want to use in center u can use android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical" as well

Comment: `center` is a combination of `center_horizontal` and `center_vertical`, so it is redundant to put any more than just `"center"`.

Comment: get it very well, tnx so much :)